# How to get MVC ActionResult in External Javascript File

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am confuse how to achieve this

I have a external javascript file let say script.js and one `<div>` tag in HTML file.
for example

```
<script src='script.js Full Path'></script>
<div id="div1">

</div>
```

Now, in my script.js file, i have ajax get function which calls Controller Action like below

```
 $(function () {

 var url = 'http://www.example.com/controller/GetHTML';
   $.get(url, function (data) {

        $('#div1').html(data);

    });
 });

 and Controller Action is

  public ActionResult GetHTML()
    {
        return View();
    } 

  and view for GetHTML Action is 

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetHTML";
    Layout = null;
     }

   <h2>This is HTML View</h2>
```

Now, i want render View as `HTML` in to `div1`, Even if i am not sure it's possible or not

So, Please any guys can help me to achieve above, it will really help me a lot.

Comment: What issue you are facing? Above statement you've added will surely fullfill your requirement

Comment: But i am not getting any response as html in div1 i don't know whats the problem..

Comment: Try to alert the data and let me know the output. and also please paste your action method code as well

Comment: @KD i have edited the question.. please suggest

Comment: Check this url
var url = "http://www.example.com/controller/GetHTML";
You havn't added controller name here

Answer (score 1):

Enter your URL Correctly... The controller name is missing i think

```
$(function () {

 var url = 'http://www.example.com/YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME/GetHTML';
   $.get(url, function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#div1').html(data);

    });
 });
```

Comment: No i am giving correct url, if i access the url in browser the view renders correct as "This is HTML View" in browser. but i want this html in my div1 and i have a separate HTML file containing div1 and script.js as mention in question.

Comment: I hope you are not having Cross domain calls by d way :)

Comment: I think you are right!! we need either JSON or XML data type in response... and thanks for you time and support.